# Implementation of iterator pattern for any array of elements

Tags: java, reinventing-the-wheel, generics, iterator

I have implemented Iterator pattern:

The interface Container.java:

```
public interface Container<T> {

    Iterator<T> getIterator();
}
```

Interface Iterator.java:

```
public interface Iterator<T>{

    boolean hasNext();

    T next();
}
```

Class ResourceContainer.java:

```
public class ResourceContainer<T extends Serializable> implements Container<T>{

    private T names [];

    public ResourceContainer(T [] names){
        this.names = names;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<T> getIterator() {      
        return new ResourceIterator<T>(this.names);
    }

}
```

Class ResourceIterator.java:

```
public class ResourceIterator<T extends Serializable> implements Iterator<T>{

    private T [] names;
    private int index;

    public ResourceIterator(T [] names){
        this.names = names;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        boolean flag = false;

        if(this.index < this.names.length){
            flag = true;
        }

        return flag;
    }

    @Override
    public T next() {               
        return this.names[index++];
    }

}
```

An `EmployeeVO` class:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class EmployeeVO implements Serializable{

    private String name;
    private Integer id;
    private String departmentName;

    public EmployeeVO(Integer id, String name, String departmentName){
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
        this.departmentName = departmentName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        StringBuffer strb = new StringBuffer();

        strb.append(" Id \"").append(this.id).append("\"")
            .append(" Name \"").append(this.name).append("\"")
            .append(" Department \"").append(this.departmentName).append("\"");

        return strb.toString();     
    }
}
```

Main class:

```
public class MainClass {    

    public static void main(String [] args){        

        Integer [] nums = new Integer[]{12,23,100,1};

        Container<Integer> container01 = new ResourceContainer<Integer>(nums);
        Iterator<Integer> itr01 = container01.getIterator();

        while(itr01.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(itr01.next());
        }

        String [] names = new String[]{ "Alan", "Jim", "Nicholas" };

        Container<String> container02 = new ResourceContainer<String>(names);
        Iterator<String> itr02 = container02.getIterator();

        while(itr02.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(itr02.next());
        }

        EmployeeVO [] employees = new EmployeeVO[] {
        new EmployeeVO(23, "Alan Turing", "Computer Science"),
        new EmployeeVO(45, "Jim Klaus", "Mechanical Engineering"),
        new EmployeeVO(76, "Nicholas Johanson", "Electrical Engineering")
        };

        Container<EmployeeVO> container03 = new ResourceContainer<EmployeeVO>(employees);
        Iterator<EmployeeVO> itr03 = container03.getIterator();

        while(itr03.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(itr03.next());
        }
    }
}
```

The output of when I run `MainClass` from the command line:

```
12
23
100
1
Alan
Jim
Nicholas
Id "23" Name "Alan Turing" Department "Computer Science"
Id "45" Name "Jim Klaus" Department "Mechanical Engineering"
Id "76" Name "Nicholas Johanson" Department "Electrical Engineering"
```

By following the code, please review and let me know whether I implemented the iterator pattern properly. Is the usage of generics proper? Can the implementation be further improved?

Comment: I assume that you are deliberately [tag:reinventing-the-wheel] by not using `java.util.Iterator`?

Comment: I am learning Design patterns, hence I am just trying iterator my own

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterator pattern/iterator class](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/2811/iterator-pattern-iterator-class)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have two points for improvement:

1. Right now `next()` method increments the index. What happens if someone calls `next()` without calling `hasNext()` method?

   - *Take care of `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` or increment the index carefully*.
2. You could implement `remove()` method (Optional)